# Can someone explain how this python-telegram-bot works in a dumbed down version

Tags: python, telegram

Little background: I have been trying to make a telegram bot using the python-telegram-bot library While I have been successful in some areas, I feel difficulty in under standing some parts of the code. For example,

```
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler

def start(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Hello!")

start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
```

I'd be glad if someone explained it in psuedo-code what is happening in this small piece of code. I couldn't find any info on effective_chat.id nor on the arguments that start takes(update and context) on google or in the docs.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: i am not familiar with the Telegram API, my answer comes from a little bit of googling and general experience

This line initializes a CommandHandler. The arguments are (command: string, handler: function). This object is responsible for handling the 'start' command.

```
start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
```

I'm guessing there is some `dispatcher` object that you have initialized previously. This looks like the dispatcher has a list of handlers, and you just register your own for the `start` command. Whenever a user sends a command, the dispatcher will try to find the appropriate handler to handle this command.

If you had not added your handler, then the `start` command would not be handled at all. But now you are effectively telling that when the `start` command is sent, use the `start_handler` (the CommandHandler from above) to handle it.

```
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
```

This is the function that will run when the `start` command is sent. The update seems to be something that wraps around the user's action. The context is some object that the library provides which contains the bot and probably other information about the connection and the channel.

Inside the handler, you are telling the bot to send back a message. To send a message you probably need the chat_id which specifies on which chat the message should go to. The chat_id is provided through the update. It seems to be a unique identifier for a chat between two (or possible more?) users.

From the documentation (https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.update.html#telegram.Update.effective_chat) it seems that the `effective_chat` is an object that provides information about the chat that the message was sent to (in this case, the '/start' command). This allows you to know where to reply to.

```
def start(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Hello!")
```